# What's the most efficient way to include Vespa document keywords in ranking at query time?

Tags: multilabel-classification, keyword-search, vespa

We have a situation where we want to search text against category documents, which are enriched by a keywords field. These keywords are terms and phrases curated by subject matter experts and GPT.

We want to be able to use queries ranging in length from 1 word to a medium sized paragraph, which will return the most suitable category based (primarily) on the keywords field.

We have the following test setup in our schema:

```
document category {

        field id type int {
            indexing: summary | attribute
        }

        field title type string {
            indexing: summary | attribute | index
            index: enable-bm25
        }

        field keywords type array<string> {
            indexing: summary | index
        }
}

field title_embedding type tensor<bfloat16>(x[384]) {
        indexing: input title | embed bert | attribute | index
        attribute {
            distance-metric: angular
        }
    }

fieldset default {
        fields: title
    }
```

We have tried the following profile:

```
rank-profile bm25_semantic inherits default {
        inputs {
            query(query_embedding) tensor<bfloat16>(x[384])
        }
        first-phase {
            expression: bm25(title) + matches(keywords) + closeness(field, title_embedding)
        }
    }
```

Together with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE userQuery() OR rank(keywords contains 'X' OR keywords contains 'Y') OR ({targetHits: 100}nearestNeighbor(title_embedding,query_embedding))
```

We have been able to get decent results with this configuration, but it's not scalable because:

1. the `keywords contains 'X'` argument needs to be repeated potentially many times depending on the query, as 'X' and 'Y' represent tokens in the query.
   EG: `query="Here is a sample text about mice and mosquitos"` which would give: `"...OR keywords contains 'mice' OR keywords contains 'mosquitos'..."`
2. the keywords and query can be in different languages which will not perform well with basic tokenisation eg: Chinese.

Essentially we're looking for a solution which is the inverse of the `contains` argument. So instead of `keywords contains "text"`, we need something like `"text" contains keywords` where the keywords are ideally included in the index.

We are still fairly new to Vespa, so we're not sure the proper approach to handling keywords. Is a different data/field structure setup required to handle this, or can this be done by building out a dedicated rank profile?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"we're looking for a solution which is the inverse of the contains argument."

This operator is called [weightedSet](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/query-language-reference.html#weightedset): `where weightedSet(keywords, {"mice":1, "mosquitos":1})`

On queries and keywords in different languages: No tokenization is done on the individual tokens you pass in YQL, for that you need to pass in raw text with [userQuery](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/query-language-reference.html#userquery), and then you can control it by setting a [grammar](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/query-language-reference.html#grammar) parameter.